# Spatial autocorrelation of a genomic variable in GAM models in R

Tags: r, spatial, modeling, gam, genome

I have a question regarding the need of using some spatial correction when modelling gene variables.

The variables that I have are:

Chr, gene_start, gene_end, number_of_bases_with_info, diversity_before, diversity_after, delta_diversity, recombination, divergence, GC_content, selection_coefficient.

My response variable is: the lost in diversity (delta_diversity), which is diversity_before-diversity_after.

My explanatory variables are: recombination, divergence, GC_content and selection coefficient.

However, I am also considering the diversity at the beginning (diversity_before), as the lost in diversity might be conditioned on the initial diversity, and number_of_bases_with_info, that ideally should be gene_end-gene_start, but sometimes we lack information of some position, and hence, it could be less.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
library(mgcv)

    model <- gam (delta_diversity ~
                        s(number_of_bases_with_info, bs="tp", k=10) +
                        s(diversity_before,  bs="tp", k=10) +
                        s(recombination, bs="tp", k=10, m=2)+
                        s(divergence,  bs="tp", k=10)+
                        s(GC_content,  bs="tp", k=10)+
                        s(selection_coefficient,  bs="tp", k=10),
                        # Dataframe
                        data=dataframe,  
                        # Method and family
                        method="REML", family="gaussian")
```

However, my residuals plots look awful!

[image]

I was wondering whether not considering spatial autocorrelation has any effect on these patterns, and how to consider it, because, as far as I know, the usual approach is:

```
corExp(form=~Latitude + Longitude)
```

which doesn't apply here, as I have coordinates (from position x to position y) within a chr.

My questions are:

Could not considering the spatial correlation be responsible for this weird residuals pattern?

Shall I consider it, and how?

Any other input about why my residuals looks so weird, or how to improve my model is more than welcome.